# How to draw a line in D3 using csv

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw a line in D3 using point data obtained from CSV input. While I can cycle through my data (in `dataSet`), is it even possible to assign `x2` and `y2` coordinates from the next index?

```
//variable 'dataSet' holds all data points
//x-coordinate in index [0], and y-coordinate in index [1]

svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d){
      return d[0];
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d){
      return d[1];
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d){
      return d[0]; //here's the problem, how can I access the next x-coordinate?
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d){
      return d[1]; //here's the problem, how can I access the next y-coordinate?
    })                
    .attr("interpolate", "linear")
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback provided to [`selection.attr()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) will be passed the current index as the second argument along with the datum as the first argument. This index can be used to access the next element in the original `dataSet` bound to the selection:

```
.attr("x2", function(d, i) {   // d is the datum, i is the index
   return dataSet[i+1][0];     // Peek ahead to the next element of the data array
}
```

In fact, in the callbacks you can safely assume that `d === dataSet[i]`.

Keep in mind, though, that—when peeking ahead—this will eventually throw a `RangeError` for the last datum because `i + 1` will refer to a non-existing next-to-last element. To safeguard against this you need to implement a check which, depending on your scenario, could be something like this:

1. Draw a zero-length line to visually end the connected lines:

   ```
   dataSet[Math.min(i + 1, dataSet.length - 1)]
   ```
2. Close the lines by connecting the last to the first point:

   ```
   dataSet[(i + 1) % dataSet.length]
   ```

Putting all that together your solution might look like this:

```
var len = dataSet.length;

function next(i) {
  var nextIndex = Math.min(i + 1, len - 1);  // open 
  // var nextIndex =(i + 1) % len;           // closed
  return dataSet[nextIndex];
}

svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter().append("line")
    // ... set x1, x2
    .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
      return next(i)[0];
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
      return next(i)[1];
    });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks altocumulus, that makes perfect sense! As I'm still getting used to this 'data(dataSet).enter()...' idiom, can you please help me further by letting me know how I can go through all the elements of 'dataSet' without iterating through the last element (because then i+1 would throw an exception error). Typically for many other languages, you'd tell the compiler to stop at (array.length - 1), but I'm not sure how this would be done here.

Comment: You have to implement a check, which largely depends on what you are looking for at the end of the connected lines. 1) No further line: `return dataSet[Math.min(i + 1, dataSet.length - 1)]` — 2) Closed to the very first point: `return dataSet[(i + 1) % dataSet.length]`.

Comment: Very clever use of the remainder.